# Malloc for char** results in a corrupted top size

Tags: c, config

I am making a config reader for an application I am making. What I am trying to fix is that whenever I add another entry '{}' to the config, it will break the application. I have pinpointed the problem, but have no idea how to go about this.

C (config.c):

```
#include <config.h>

struct Config read_config(char * cfg) {
    struct Config newCfg;
    newCfg.valuesSize = 0;
    int configIsMalloc = 0;

    char * config;
    if (file_exists(cfg)==0) { 
        config = cfg;
    }
    else {
       config = read_file(cfg);
       configIsMalloc=1;
    }

    newCfg.values = (char****)malloc(sizeof(char****)*strlen(config));
    int valuesPtr = 0;
    int needsMalloc = 1;

    while(config) {
        char * nextLine = strchr(config, '\n');
        if (nextLine) *nextLine = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", config);

        if (config[0] == '{') {
            if (needsMalloc==0) {
                //newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize] = (char***)realloc(newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize], newCfg.valuesSize*(sizeof(char***)*sizeof(config)));
            }
            else {
                newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize] = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char***)*strlen(config));
                needsMalloc=0;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(config, "}")) {
            newCfg.valuesSize++;
            valuesPtr=0;
        }

        // The culprit lies here...
        else if (strstr(config, ":")) {
            newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr] = (char**)malloc(1000);

            char * split = strtok(config, ":");
            newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr][0] = (char*)malloc(strlen(split)*sizeof(char));
            strcat(newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr][0], split);

            split = strtok(NULL, ":");
            newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr][1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(split)*sizeof(char));
            strcat(newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr][1], split);
            valuesPtr++;
        }

        if (nextLine) *nextLine = '\n';
        config = nextLine ? (nextLine+1) : NULL;
    }

    (configIsMalloc==1) ? free(config) : NULL;
    return newCfg;
}
```

config.h defines the struct for storing config information C (config.h):

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <files.h>

struct Config {
char *** values;
int valuesSize;
};

struct Config read_config(char * cfg);

#endif
```

This contains information for the config reader to pick up This is read from a file in my program test-config:

```
{
ID:001
TITLE:Russian Spy Infiltration
DESCRIPTION:Those darn russian spies have done it again.
}

{
ID:002
TITLE:American Enthusiasts
DESCRIPTION:America!!!!!
}
```

The error that prints

```
{
ID:001
TITLE:Russian Spy Infiltration
DESCRIPTION:Those darn russian spies have done it again.
}
{
ID:002
malloc(): corrupted top size
fish: Job 1, './bm' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

EDIT: Instead of using sizeof(), I replaced them with strlen()

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are using not enough stars yet.:) The previous time (in previous your question) you used less numbers of stars.:) So there is some progress.:)

Comment: Holy sh. A four-star programmer!

Answer (score 2):

```
        newCfg.values[newCfg.valuesSize][valuesPtr][0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(split)*sizeof(char));
```

Why `sizeof(split)`? That's the same as `sizeof(char*)`, which is obviously wrong. Did you mean to use `strlen`?

Comment: I fixed the code so that sizeof() for char* is instead strlen(), but the problem still remains unfortunately.

Comment: @EvanPisarsky Not surprising. That is what we call "write only" code.

Answer (score 0):

Also, given `

```
struct Config {
char *** values;
int valuesSize;
};
```

and

```
char * config;
```

this line has two problems:

```
newCfg.values = (char****)malloc(sizeof(char****)*sizeof(config));`
```

First, `sizeof(config)` is the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to (and it points to a `char` of size one...).  You probably wanted `strlen()`.  Maybe.

And you are using `sizeof(char****)` even though `values` is a `char ***`.  That won't cause a problem with the size on most systems, but it's still wrong.  And if you follow the pattern, it *will* cause serious problems with smaller numbers if `*`s.

And many would say there's a third problem - [you don't cast the return value from `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I went ahead and fixed up the memory issues you mentioned, which makes the code look better, but unfortunately didn't fix the issue